# Android Studio Error 404 in Post by HttpURLConnection

Tags: android

I am getting 404 error while connecting to webservices. I have added internet permission in manifest as well.

```
try {

  URL url_post = new URL("MyWebservice"); // here is your URL path

  JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
  postDataParams.put("clienteadd", tv_cedula.getText().toString() );
  postDataParams.put("tarjeta", tv_tarjeta.getText().toString());
  postDataParams.put("cvv", tv_codigo_cvv.getText().toString());
  postDataParams.put("FECHA", Calendar.getInstance().toString());
  postDataParams.put("CODIGO_POSTAL", tv_codigo_postal.getText().toString());
  postDataParams.put("CORREO", tv_correo.getText().toString());
  postDataParams.put("CIUDAD", tv_ciudad.getText().toString());
  postDataParams.put("PASWORD", tv_contrasenia.getText().toString());
  postDataParams.put("TELEFONO", tv_telefono.getText().toString());
  postDataParams.put("NOMBRE", tv_nombre.getText().toString());
  postDataParams.put("APELLIDO", tv_apellido.getText().toString());
  postDataParams.put("MES_TARJETA", "2");
  postDataParams.put("ANIO_TARJETA", "3");

  Log.e("params",postDataParams.toString());


  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url_post.openConnection();
  conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
  conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
  conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
  conn.setRequestProperty ("User-agent", "mozilla");
  conn.setDoInput(true);
  conn.setDoOutput(true);

  OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
  BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
  writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getPostDataString(postDataParams) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  writer.flush();
  writer.close();
  os.close();

  int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

  if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

    BufferedReader in2 =new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
            conn.getInputStream()));
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
    String line2 ="";

    while((line2 = in2.readLine()) != null) {

      sb.append(line2);
      break;
    }

    in.close();

  }
  else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error : "+responseCode , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception: " + e.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public String getPostDataString(JSONObject params) throws Exception {

  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
  boolean first = true;

  Iterator<String> itr = params.keys();

  while(itr.hasNext()){

    String key= itr.next();
    Object value = params.get(key);

    if (first)
      first = false;
    else
      result.append("&");

    result.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
    result.append("=");
    result.append(URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "UTF-8"));

  }
  return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Remove conn.setDoInput(true);

Comment: Did you check your url working in postman

Comment: yes, in postman it works well.

Comment: Are you using local host or any server if server means you can access from any network. If you are local host means client and server to be in same network.

Comment: Did you remove setDoInput and check

Comment: Yes, I remove setDoInput but it still doesn't work.
Yes, I can access from any network, the get works well.

Comment: is the url formatted? it should start with http:// or https://

Comment: Starts with htttp://

Answer (score 0):

You need to correctly inform the server for the request info. Try adding the following:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
```

Comment: Just to make sure, are you correctly set the url in the line `URL url_post = new URL("MyWebservice");`?